# Missing options in "NVIDIA X Server Settings"

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics, xubuntu

In my new laptop ASUS ROG GL GL552VW I've installed Nvidia Binary driver and microcode from additional drivers, I've reboot the system in NVIDIA X Server settings there are no options like in [tutorial here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/)

it look like this:

[image]

What should I do to make it look like in the tutorial so I can switch to nvidia graphic card?

Comment: Can you disable the Intel iGPU in the BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue when I installed Xubuntu 16.10, I needed to remove `nomodeset` from kernel option in grub that after installing the drivers.